# Updating List from JSON data SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine, swiftui-list

I'm having a hard time understanding how JSON data is supposed to be updated in a List in SwiftUI. I'm fetching data from NewsAPI.org, my list and detail views work just fine. I'm trying to figure out how to keep the list up-to-date when my json data changes, but the data remains outdated. I'm still a beginner to swift so if I made a mistake any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED
Attempted to use combine with the same results, outdated data

New data class

```
class NewsData: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NewsData, Never>()
    
    @Published var articles = [Article]() {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.articles = response.articles
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
    
    /*
    init() {
        URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY")!))
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: News.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { data in
                self.articles = data.articles
            })
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
    */
    
    /*
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.articles = response.articles
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
    */
}
```

My data old class

```
struct News : Codable {
    var articles : [Article]
}

struct Article : Codable {
    let description : String?
    let title : String?
    let author: String?
    let source: Source
    let content: String?
    let publishedAt: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let name: String?
}

class NewsData: ObservableObject {
   @Published var news: News = News(articles: [])
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=API_KEY_HERE") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.news = response
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

My ContentView

```
func relativeDate(date: String) -> String {
    let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    return formatter.localizedString(for: dateFormatter.date(from: date) ?? Date(), relativeTo: Date())
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var news: NewsData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(news.news.articles , id: \.title) { article in
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                    Text(article.title ?? "")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    Text(article.description ?? "")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                   Text(relativeDate(date: article.publishedAt ?? ""))
                         .font(.subheadline)
                         .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("News")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks that if `news` in `NewsData` changed, it will update. Should you not just call `load()` every few minutes, or however often you would like? I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for or not, but from what I can see the SwiftUI code looks correct.

Comment: @George_E I assumed using the `@ObservedObject` would automatically update said data when it changes, maybe I'm missing something? Calling the load() function I thought wasn't necessary in SwiftUI when checking for any data changes? I'm still very new to swift so still not sure.

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. `@ObservedObject` will update the view body, whenever a change is made to a `@Published` property (or manually updating, which is not relevant in this case). This means that when the value of `news` in the object has changed, the view will update. From what you have here, you only call `load()` initially. However SwiftUI does not call your `load()` function, but when you do call that however often you want, `news` will update, and therefore the view body will update. Hope that made sense, but ask if you are still a bit confused.

Comment: @George_E I went with combine and hoped it would have worked but it hasn’t. I’d rather not use a Timer if that’s what you were referring to? I’ve seen some examples that do almost the same as my code but I can’t figure out how they keep their data updated.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know enough about Combine for this, but I will say you don't need the `objectWillChange.send` and stuff you added, since `Article` is a struct and `articles` is already `@Published`.

Comment: @George_E I've even seen an [example](https://finsi-ennes.medium.com/build-and-update-lists-automatically-with-swiftui-and-combine-fde0cbd773f1) online that does something similar but I've tested an no data will be updated